# Form Validation Issue with using (onBlur) event in p-calendar under FormGroup

Tags: angular, primeng

I am updating the P-calendar model value onblur event, Even though the formcontrol is valid after the model update, but the form validation throws false.

**html**

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form" class="box-model form-support-margin">
  <div class="col-md-10  col-sm-12  col-xs-12">
    <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="tbDate" [dateFormat]="dateFormat" 
      [showIcon]="true" formControlName="tbDate"  readonlyInput="false"
      (onBlur)="tbDateChange($event)">
    </p-calendar>    
  </div>  
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Pipe, ChangeDetectorRef, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import * as moment from 'moment'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
   templateUrl: "address.component.html",
})

export class AddressComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(   private fb: FormBuilder){}

   ngOnInit() {
     this.initFormGroup();
   }

   initFormGroup() {
     this.form = this.fb.group({
       tbDate:  new FormControl(this.tbDate|| '', Validators.required);
     });
   }

   tbDateChange(event: any) {
      let time = event.srcElement.value;
      let d = new Date();
      this.tbDate=d;
   }       
 }
```

Comment: You're using both ngModel and formControlName, and idk what `tbDateChange` is even doing, what is `this.date`?

Comment: Yes i am using both ngModel & FormControlName. tbDateChange event is used assign current Date in OnBlur event like while user press F11 key. Sorry  this.date->this.tbDate  ngModel.

Comment: You can't use both ngModel and formControlName.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz without  formControlName the FormGroup will throw error. And i need ngModel it's working fine for other properties only in p-calendar onBlur event the form validation throws false.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz (onBlur) event the value is assigned to ngModel but the  form validation throws false?

Comment: The date will already be bound to `tbDate`.. you don't need ngModel or blur event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149702/discussion-between-vignesh-and-chrillewoodz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p-calendar` automatically validates the date when it's entered with slash '/' which makes the form valid too. So, I used this feature to solve your issue letting users manually enter the date.

In my example,  '/' automatically gets added after user inputs month and day. I also added input validation so that only numbers can be entered.

html:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form" class="box-model form-support-margin">
  <div class="col-md-10  col-sm-12  col-xs-12">
    <p-calendar  [dateFormat]="dateFormat" [(ngModel)]="modelVal"
      [showIcon]="true" formControlName="tbDate"  [readonlyInput]="false"
      (keydown)="onlyNumbers($event)"
      (keyup)="addSlash($event)">
    </p-calendar>    
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <button md-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" class="" [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>
</form>
```

ts:

```
 dateFormat: = "mm/dd/yy"

  constructor(   private fb: FormBuilder){}

   ngOnInit() {
     this.initFormGroup();
   }

   initFormGroup() {
     this.form = this.fb.group({
       tbDate:  new FormControl(this.tbDate|| '', Validators.required);
     });
   }

   addSlash($event){
     if(event.code != "Backspace" && (event.srcElement.value.length == 2 || event.srcElement.value.length == 5)){
       event.srcElement.value += '/';
     }
   }

   onlyNumbers(event){
     if(event.code == "Backspace" 
        || event.code == "ArrowLeft"
        || event.code == "ArrowRight"){
       return true;
     }
     if(event.srcElement.value.length < 10){
       if((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57)
           || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105))
          return true;
      else
        return false;
     }
     else
        return false;
   }
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/DcMUCWQ9u4a3yekrNbO9?p=preview)

Hope this workaround resolves your issue :)